# Invalid use of registers while calling printf

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

My Code:

```
.386
.model small,c
.stack 1000h

.data
msg     db  34h


.code
includelib MSVCRT
extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
    
         push offset msg
         call printf
         mov al, 0fh       ; hex=0fh=dec15  
         mov bl, 0eh      ; hex=0eh=dec14
         add bl, al
         push offset bl
         call printf         
         push 0
         call exit
main endp

end main
```

- I am successfully able to print `4` using first `prinf`.
- Then i moved 15 and 14 to al and bl respectively.
- Then i used `add` to add them and store result in `bl`
- Now i want to print the answer (its stored in `bl`)
- Whenever i try to use printf it gives an error:

  > error A2032: invalid use of register

What i tried:

- `mov bl,eax` then print
- `mov eax,bl` then print
- print `bl` directly

Then i finally tried this:

```
mov al,3 ;print ♥
mov dl,al
mov ah,76
int 21h ;call interrupt
```

All fail.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am on `x86`

**EDIT2:** After some research , i am finally able to almost get this working:

Here's my new code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.data
msg     dd  34h
fmt    db "Value is : %d", 0

.data?
retvalue dd ?

.code
include windows.inc
include user32.inc
includelib user32.lib
include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib MSVCRT
extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
    
         ;push offset msg
         ;call printf
         mov eax, 1Eh       ; Decimal=30
         mov ecx, 1Eh     ; Decimal=30
         add eax, ecx
         mov retvalue,eax
         push offset retvalue
         push offset fmt
         call printf 
      push 0
         call exit
main endp

end main
```

The Problem is that the final `printf` prints rubbish numbers:

here's the output: `Value is : 4206612`

Expected output : `Value is : 60`

Comment: You really should learn about using `printf`'s formatting options, and how `printf` works in general. You can create a format string like `%d`. `%d` would print an integer. In that case you push the register with the value you want to print, the format string second and call `printf` . Registers don't have memory addresses so the `offset` is an error when it appears in front of a register.

Comment: You can forget about `int 21h ;call interrupt` if you are targeting 32-bit Windows. That is for DOS.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Do you mean, http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/nasm/sample.shtml#printf1 ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch See my edit2

Comment: The format part is correct, but the `"%d"` means I'm passing an integer as the next argument (not an address). Push the 32-bit bit register you wish to print onto the stack directly. In your case remove `mov  retvalue,eax` and `push offset retvalue` and replace with `push eax`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks :)